# making images smaller after mutiple selection of images using shift or control and click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

hi am selecting multiple images present in a div and am trowing that images in another div using jquery ui sortable.when am selecting the multiple images.i want to club or animated that images to a single image effect using jquery.can any one help me.how to do that in jquery..Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this beautiful drag and drop plugin using jquery... Hope this work for you... Thanks...

http://dragsort.codeplex.com/